# Angularjs $http can't read my RESTful app

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am working on a small project that has a RESTful api and now I need to connect it to my Angular.js frontend in order to bring it all together and start working on the GUI. I have tested out my api thoroughly and it works fine from multiple sources and multiple test programs/locations so I am fairly certain that it is not a server side problem.

I am using the following code to attempt connection with the api but it never gets out:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('expenseAPI', []);
  app.controller('ExpenseController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
      var user = {
        username: "Richard",
        password: 11111
      };
      $scope.registerUser = function() {
        console.log("sending data");
        $http.post('https://apiserver/user', user).success(function(data) {
          $scope.result = data;});
      });
    };
  }
]);
}());
```

I have tried manually editing the api call as well as calling different endpoints but it still doesn't go through. Can you tell me what mistake I am making or if maybe there is an easier way of doing this?

Update: after some more testing the problem still isn't resolved. It sends the authorization header properly and responds with 401 on appropriate routes if authorization fails. Also, this particular request (supposed to make a new user in the database) returns a status 200 but the base doesn't get updated and the promise returns a failure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't go through'? Do you see any traffic in the developer console's network tab?

Comment: What error do you see 404 , 501 etc ?

Comment: Is your api server by chance written in PHP?  Is so, PHP doesn't read `POST` data the way Angular sends it by default.  If you `var_dump` the `$_POST` array it will be empty.  To get the data sent you need to do `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_content('php://input'), true));`

Comment: You might have CORS issue. You cannot make ajax requests to a remote URL. What do you see in console?

Comment: Ok, I re tested and the network tab returns a 200, as if the request went through, however, the database on the server doesn't get updated, i e this function should be making a new user instance in the database but it doesn't.

The database server is running node with express and mongo db.

When I tested the call with curl, hurl.com, Chrome's Posman and FF Poster addon they all worked fine, returned the proper response and updated the base appropriately.